# Finding the longest palindromic substring

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, python-2.x, palindrome

I have the following code that works correctly. I am wondering if there is a simpler way to go about implementing my solution and/or if there is anything that looks non-standard in my code. If anyone wants to offer criticism I'm all ears.

```
### Question 2 main function and helper functions.
"""Given a string a, find the longest palindromic substring contained in a.
Your function definition should look like question2(a), and return a string."""
# Gives substrings of s in decending order.
def substrings(s):

    # Declare local variable for the length of s.
    l = len(s)

    # Here I chose range over xrange for python version compatibility.
    for end in range(l, 0, -1):
        for i in range(l-end+1):
            yield s[i: i+end]

# Define palindrome.
def palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]

# Main function.
def Question2(a):
    for l in substrings(a):
        if palindrome(l):
            return l

# Simple test case.
print Question2("stresseddesserts")
# stresseddesserts
```

Comment: Just one thing – change comments from `#...` above functions to docstrings inside functions.

Comment: The variable you call *end* isn't an end. It's a length or span: `s[i: i+end]` instead of `s[i:end]`. And look at the acrobatics you pull with `for i in range(l-end+1):` ... that's really just a severely obfuscated way of writing nested loops with indices `for i in range(l): ... for j in range(l, 0, -1):` then reference `s[i:j]`

Comment: Bug: Also, your main loop `for l in substrings(a): ...` will return *the first* palindrome it finds inside a (stepping the indices back from the end), not just the longest one. If there are multiple longest palindromes it won't return them all. Your code is overly tailored to this one example. Use other examples to tickle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In terms of efficiency, I like the code.

I'd just fix a few stylistic issues:

- Naming: `l`, `a`, `s` don't say anything about what the variable means. Also, you named your function `palindrome`, but that's returning a boolean, so I'd name it `is_palindrome`. The `i` in the `substring` function is a bit puzzling to me: you have a variable named `end`, why not call the other one `start`?
- As @kyrill mentioned, you should probably change comments above the functions to docstrings.
- The comment `Declare local variable for the length of s.` is useless.
- I'd instead add another comment explaining why it works. If you have a function simply called `substrings` I expect it to return the substrings. This code only works because it returns the substrings starting from the longest to the shortest. I'd at least change the comment `descending order` (which may mean for example lexicographical order or alphabetical order) to `from longest to shortest`. Better be explicit.
- I know, it's a bit long, but since you're using a generator, I'd rename the function `substrings` to `get_next_substring`.
- As @zondo mentioned `Question2` is not a PEP8 compliant name, but I'm not sure if the automatic grader will need it to be called like that.

Comment: `get_next_substring` would be a misleading name. The function does not return the next substring – when you call it, you get a generator. And that generator returns the next substring when you call its `__next__` method. So I think `substrings` is a more apt name.

Comment: @kyrill What you say is correct of course, but seeing how the function is used, it really looks like it's returning a list and that's not the case, that's why I think `substrings` is not a good enough name. As you say, also `get_next_substring` is not perfect, but I couldn't come up with anything better.

Comment: I don't see why returning a generator instead of a list means that `substrings` is a misleading name. You would still do `for substring in substrings(...)`, and other similar things. A generator is still a sequence in many respects.

Answer (score 3):

I saw your `substrings` function and expected to tell you to use `yield` instead of creating a list, but you already do. I also like your comment on why you use `range`. If you want to be *completely* compatible with Python 3, though, you'll need to use parentheses for `print`:

```
print(Question2("stresseddesserts"))
```

The only other thing I'll mention is that `Question2` does not follow official Python naming guidelines as defined in PEP 8. According to that document, function names should use snake_case. Your assignment also uses lowercase, so I'm a little surprised you changed it especially since your other functions are lowercase.

All in all, the program is concise, efficient, and organized. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

1. BUG: Your main loop `for l in substrings(a): ...` will return the **first** palindrome it finds inside `a` (stepping the indices back from the end), not just the longest one. If there are multiple longest palindromes it won't return them all, only the first it finds. Your code is overly tailored to this one example. Use other examples to tickle it, e.g. *"zaba effeffe xyx"*. Your main function should yield all candidates of longest length (or else keep a list), only then can it finish.
2. Obfuscated loop variables:

   - `l` is totally unnecessary, get rid of it
   - The variable you call `end` isn't an end. It's a length or span: `s[i: i+end]` instead of `s[i:end]`. And look at the acrobatics you pull with `for i in range(l-end+1): ...` that's really just a severely obfuscated way of writing nested loops with indices:

```
    for i in range(l):
      for j in range(l, i, -1):
        # Now reference s[i:j]
```

3. But that iterator function `substrings()` is just a verbose way of doing what a generator expression or list comprehension could do in one line:

`s[i:j] for i in range(l) for j in range(l, i, -1)`

4. INEFFICIENCY: your loop only needs to run the `j/end` index as far back as `i`, not 0. Once j < i, then `s[i:j]` will be empty-string, that's ~2x wasted iterations.